# Concat dataframes efficiently

Tags: pandas

Here is the concat method that works correctly.

```
pd.concat([myd['a'], myd['b']], axis=1)

    YearFrom    cnt YearFrom    cnt
0   1001    9   1001    2
1   2010    3   2010    1
2   2011    199787  2011    127485
3   2012    214548  2012    144348
4   2013    991 2013    1396
5   2014    236596  2014    159302
6   2015    241611  2015    164767
7   2016    195123  2016    162352
```

1) I want the yearFrom column to appear only once and cnt should be appended by dataframe name like cnt_a and cnt_b

2) Another issue is that there are several such dataframes stored in a dictionary. I expected the following comprehension to work. But getting an error:

```
pd.concat([[myd[i] for i in myd]], axis=1)

TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

---

Update: I need to add one column and a row to final dataframe.

this adds the total column at the end. No issues :)

```
df['total']=df.sum(axis=1)
```

this returns exactly what I need, but does not include index. I need to name this row as "sum".

```
df.append(df.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for align data by index:

```
myd = myd.set_index('YearFrom')
pd.concat([myd['a'], myd['b']], axis=1)
```

And for second:

```
df = pd.concat([v.set_index('yearFrom') for k, v in myd.items()], axis=1, keys=myd.keys())
```

For sum row need:

```
df.loc['total']=df.sum()
```

Comment: The second answer is awesome. Is it possible to get the total (per row and per column)?

Comment: Do you think for final `df` or for each `myd` ?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: And for rows use `df.loc['total']=df.sum()`